# Are there alternatives to embsysregview?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, embedded

http://embsysregview.sourceforge.net/

I'd like to avoid using eclipse if I can.  Tried googling - nothing came up.

Comment: Your question would be better formed if it described what functionality you needed rather than just using another product as an example - especially when we have to follow a link to find out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debuggers of most commercial vendors will provide that functionality, for example [Kiel MDK-ARM](http://www.keil.com/arm/mdk.asp), [IAR EWB](http://www.iar.com/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/), [Rowley Associates CrossWorks](http://www.rowley.co.uk/).

Keil and IAR both provide code-size limited evaluation versions that you can use for non-commercial and evaluation purposes (i.e. you can't sell or distribute a product built using it), Rowley have a 30 day evaluation licence (as does IAR in addition to teh code limited version).  For a full licence Rowley is by far the [least expensive](http://sites.fastspring.com/rowley/product/crossworksforarm) - largely because they use GCC rather than a proprietary compiler, but the debugger is their own and not based on GDB (and all the better for it!).

If you need free tools, [CooCox CoIDE](http://www.coocox.org/CooCox_CoIDE.htm) appears to do exactly what you want (and probably more).  It is Eclipse based, so may not meet your requirements, but all the integration is already done for you, so it is less of a kit-of-parts than assembling Eclipse with CDT and various other plug-ins.  In particular the embedded target debugging is integrated, and that is probably the most difficult part to get information on for Eclipse in my experience.